# Help with UPDATE with Custom INNER JOIN - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, inner-join

I have a table for each location type (City, Street, Country, etc).

Now i have a stored procedure which needs to return a list of "Locations", with their "highest rated Review".

I have a temporary table to hold onto the "Locations" (could be anything - Street, City, etc).

I insert into the temp table first from Cities, then Streets, then Countries, etc.

I end up with a temp table of "Locations", and for each one of those i need to grab the highest rated Review. (highest = BaseScore, e.g 5.0)

**Cardinalities:**

- Location **Many..Many** Posts (PostLocations join table)
- Post **1..1** Review
- Review **1..1** Score

Location Temp Table:

```
DECLARE @ResultSet TABLE
(
    [LocationId]                INT,
    [TopReviewId]               INT, -- starts out NULL, need to fill in
    [TopReviewContent]          NVARCHAR(MAX)  -- starts out NULL, need to fill in       
)

-- Get the Top Rated Review for each location.
    UPDATE      ResultSet
    SET         TopReviewId = TopReview.PostId, 
                TopReviewContent = TopReview.Content
    FROM        @ResultSet ResultSet
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 pl.LocationId, p.postid, p.Content
        FROM PostLocations pl
        INNER JOIN Posts p
        ON pl.PostId = p.PostId
        INNER JOIN Reviews r
        ON p.PostId = r.PostId
        INNER JOIN Scores s
        ON r.ScoreId = s.ScoreId
        INNER JOIN @ResultSet rs
        ON pl.LocationId = rs.LocationId
        ORDER BY s.BaseScore DESC
    ) AS TopReview
    ON  ResultSet.LocationId = TopReview.LocationId

    INNER JOIN  PostLocations pl
    ON          ResultSet.LocationId = pl.LocationId
    INNER JOIN  Posts p
    ON          pl.PostId = p.PostId
    INNER JOIN  Reviews r
    ON          pl.PostId = r.PostId


    -- Now return the Results:
    SELECT      TOP 10
                [LocationId],
                [TopReviewId],             
                [TopReviewContent]        

    FROM        @ResultSet
```

This is the output **i am currently getting**

```
LocationId    TopReviewId   TopReviewContent
1             12313         Blah Blah
2             NULL          NULL
3             NULL          NULL
```

This is the output **i want**

```
LocationId    TopReviewId   TopReviewContent
1             12313         Blah Blah
2             44323         Meh meh
3             5345345       Pew pew
```

Comment: Is it necessary for your task to insert into a temporary table? I think you can find the max price per customer without a temp table.

Comment: The UPDATE statement is distracting -- what is your expected output?

Comment: Maybe i shouldn't use made up tables/scenarios. I'll update the Q.

Comment: @Ramy, @OMG Ponies - Check it out now guys - again, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: so, let me see if I've got this, you just want the top review. Not the top review from each location?

Comment: @Ramy - no, i want the top review *for each location*. at the moment i'm only getting the top review (which is the issue).

Comment: check out my update. I think your problem is you're trying to upate and join to your temp table at the same time. I'm not sure why you need a temp table at all. Can you explain why you tried to use that?

Comment: @Ramy - i'm trying out your update now. As i said, i need the temp table because i need to grab a mixed bag of Locations, from the *specific* table (City, Street, Country, etc). Each of those tables have specific relationships, and complicated logic that can't be combined into a single query for the result.

Comment: and yep - your right about the UPDATE and JOIN at same time. I just dont know how to resolve it. Im thinking i need a cursor.

Comment: @RPM, if you use the query I specified in my answer in the body of your update, you should be ok. Let me know if it works.

Comment: try changing the "TopReview" inner table to the query to find the locations and their top reviews and let me know how that works out.

Comment: @Ramy - yep, that got it. Performance is pretty crap but i'll tune that. Cheers!

Comment: I"m not yet convinced you need a cursor.

Comment: Great! I'd appreciate an upvote, too if you haven't already. Thanks and happy performance tuning. :-)

Comment: Upvote added for all your help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is naive but have you tried:

```
select c.name, max(price)
from 
    customer c inner join
    product p on p.customerid = c.customerid
group by c.name
```

if you want the single best review, you'd do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 pl.LocationId, p.postid, p.Content
FROM PostLocations pl  
    INNER JOIN Posts p  
        ON pl.PostId = p.PostId  
    INNER JOIN Reviews r  
        ON p.PostId = r.PostId  
    INNER JOIN Scores s  
        ON r.ScoreId = s.ScoreId  
ORDER BY s.BaseScore DESC
```

If you want the best review per location, you'd do this:

```
SELECT pl.LocationId, p.postid, p.Content, max(s.BaseScore)
FROM PostLocations pl  
    INNER JOIN Posts p    
    ON pl.PostId = p.PostId  
    INNER JOIN Reviews r  
    ON p.PostId = r.PostId  
    INNER JOIN Scores s  
    ON r.ScoreId = s.ScoreId  
group by p1.locationid, p.postid, p.content
```

Answer (score 0):

I am bit confused as to what you are trying to do. but to get the list of customers along with their highest order ID, couldn't you just do this?

```
select customers.name, orders.orderid 
from customers join orders on customers.customerid = orders.customerid 
group by customers.customerid 
having max(orders.price);
```